# Find a Square from n given Points.

Tags: geometry, optimization

Given set X of m Integeral Cords. I need to add minimum number of points to set X such that i get atleast one Square.

For example: lets say X:{(0,0),(2,2),(3,3)}.
Now i will have to add minimum 2 points (2,0) and (0,2) to get a square S{(0,0),(2,0),(2,2),(0,2)}.

How to approach this problem ?

Comment: This question looks very much like [How to find the number of squares formed by given lattice points?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/958381/35416) Is this some kind of homework assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the point coordinates in a hash table for fast search (quasi-constant time), or in a grid.

Now every pair of points defines two distinct squares of which it constitutes a side. You can easily check how many points are missing to complete the squares.

By exhaustive search on all pairs of points it will take time $O(m^2)$ to find the minimum.

Note that the only possible answers are $0$, $1$ or $2$.